# Writing an output on a .txt file on Powershell

Tags: powershell

I found a little script to get all the local groups and members and it's working perfectly but I need to write the output on PowerShell.

```
Trap {"Error: $_"; Break;}

function EnumLocalGroup($LocalGroup) {
    $Group = [ADSI]"WinNT://$strComputer/$LocalGroup,group"
    "`r`n" + "Group: $LocalGroup"
    $Members = @($Group.psbase.Invoke("Members"))

    foreach ($Member In $Members) {
        $Name = $Member.GetType().InvokeMember("Name", 'GetProperty', $Null, $Member, $Null)
        $Name
    }
}

$strComputer = gc env:computername
"Computer: $strComputer"
$computer = [adsi]"WinNT://$strComputer"
$objCount = ($computer.PSBase.Children | Measure-Object).Count
$i = 0
foreach ($adsiObj in $computer.PSBase.Children) {
    switch -regex ($adsiObj.PSBase.SchemaClassName) {
        "group" {
            $group = $adsiObj.Name
            EnumLocalGroup $group
        }
    }
    $i++
}
```

I already tried this:

```
function EnumLocalGroup($LocalGroup) | Out-File -FilePath "E:\PS\Malik\group.txt"
```

But the code won't start if I do that. I also tried to use this whole `Out-File` line at the end of the code after the `}` but doesn't work either and this is the only solution I find on Internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to incorporate logging into a function you need to put it into the function body, e.g.

```
function EnumLocalGroup($LocalGroup) {
    ....
    $foo = 'something'
    $foo                           # output returned by function
    $foo | Add-Content 'log.txt'   # output to log file
    ...
}
```

or

```
function EnumLocalGroup($LocalGroup) {
    ...
    $foo = 'something'
    $foo | Tee-Object 'log.txt' -Append   # output goes to log file and StdOut
    ...
}
```

Otherwise you have to do the logging when you call the function:

```
EnumLocalGroup $group | Add-Content 'C:\log.txt'
```